# MSAL Android - App was stuck at callback screen

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal

I implemented MSAL authentication on Android using Xamarin with package Microsoft.Identity.Client and it has an issue at callback screen, the authentication was successully and the token was granted but the application was stucked in callback screen. When I zoom out or rotate my device to landscape it show a "continue" button, if I pressed that button, the authentication process will complete and can callback to my app.

This problem only occurred on some android device models, so I'm not sure why the UI/UX here is incorrect.

[Figure 1: Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AePBU.png)

[Figure 2: Zoom out and continue button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRSOh.png)

[Figure 3: pop-up in landscape view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zdU.png)

Comment: Please avoid adding links to images. The link may, at some point, become unavailable and make this question unusable for future users.

Comment: thanks @gioravered for your feedback, but my account is new with this, so I don't have permission/reputation to embed images.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the version Microsoft.Identity.Client. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow